# deezer search issue,the search string includes some special characters

Tags: deezer

I am searching for a string in *deezer*

[Example 1](http://api.deezer.com/search/artist?q=%22Ntr@%22&index=0&limit=200&output=json)

It is showing empty results.
But in deezer app it is showing results

[Example 2](http://api.deezer.com/search/artist?q=%22Ntr%22&index=0&limit=200&output=json)

Results are proper matching with *deezer* app also

I want the particular format in search string that includes special characters.

Answer (score 0):

http://developers.deezer.com/api/search explains that the search returns only tracks, not podcast. Your first example returns no result in the website too in the artist section, so all is normal.

Comment: yah.. thanks for answering. but if you having deezer account give the string Ntr@ it will give you results.. whether the results are matching are not it doesn't matters... i tried in my deezer account serach  it is showing results.. the problem for me is that if i include any special characters in search string means it is showing empty results.. if you find format for url for search which is having any special characters please let me know...all the examples what 
 http://developers.deezer.com/api/search without special charcters like @,&,ë ....

Comment: For each the special char you want to include in your search, you have to encode it. For example, the "&" char will be "%26", this is how it works on the website if you look at the URL after searching "&" in the menu bar. Now you should be able to find converter on the web to handle your search.